# Hardening RPi4 for persistent 24/7 connection to public wifi

Tags: wifi, pi-4, security

**Edited**: Based on private feedback to improve Q specificity.

The public wifi is typical of that provided by libraries, airports and other public spaces that re-directs a browser to sign up or login via username and password. The RPi will be operating RPi OS and used as a basic desktop (browsing, streaming video, image/audio editing) connected to wifi 24/7.

Basic security measures.

1. SSH disabled.
2. Default username and password changed.
3. UFW installed and enabled.

I'm security conscious enough to not be concerned about malware/phishing/packet interception. My main concern, being unfamiliar with the RPi OS, will be about network vulnerabilities/port intrusions.

Will the measures be enough to reduce risk of intrusion to the level of a Windows 10 system 'out of the box' connected to public wifi in the same way?

Comment: Consider "re-casting" your question as a specific question. As currently written, it's a solicitation for opinions. No one can tell you "How sound is this for security compared to a Windows 10 system". If you want opinions, try `reddit` or the [RPi forum](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums).

Comment: There seems to be no way to reframe this topic to make it more suitable to the stackexchange format than it is, so I think the RPi forums will be more appropriate.

Comment: Yes, it's consistent across all the SE sites I use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point in time, Windows 10 can be considered a reasonably secure OS, with some sane defaults. Even so, it will be difficult to beat a Linux desktop given the proper hardening (which you seem to have in order), if only because there is so much more interest in breaking machines in the Windows ecosystem. A tool is only as good as the person wielding it though, and even Linux (and Raspberry Pi OS) makes it possible to shoot yourself in the foot. Keep this in mind, and you should be safe on that public wifi.

Now, there is a whole different discussion on what you'd want to do to make sure your conversations remain private. Since being on public wifi, you can't assume nobody is intercepting your traffic. I'd therefore recommend routing all your traffic through a VPN connection and make sure not just your machine is secure, but your traffic is as well.